# Reduce multiple IDs in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF with the layout of below. The actual table is in the range of +10m rows so on the larger side.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1' : ['12a', '13b', '14c', '15d', '16e', '18g', '17f', '19h']
                     ,'id2' : ['16e', '17f', '18g', '19h','12a', '14c','13b', '15d']
                     ,'var1' : [i for i in range(8)]
                     ,'var2' : list(np.random.randint(100, size = 8))
                     ,'var3' : [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 34]
     })
```

```
>>> df
   id1  id2  var1  var2  var3
0  12a  16e     0    66   1.0
1  13b  17f     1     9   2.0
2  14c  18g     2    48   NaN
3  15d  19h     3    13   3.0
4  16e  12a     4    67   2.0
5  18g  14c     5    88   NaN
6  17f  13b     6    92   NaN
7  19h  15d     7    99  34.0
```

What I want is to reduce the IDs in the DF, which goes in pairs, e.g. *id1* index row 0 with *id2* index row 4. All ids exist on two rows and I need to check every row and remove one of the rows. Currently I have a solution-ish which is row itteration and a bit slow.

Please note that one cant just drop the lower part of the DF (index row 4 and onwards) since all IDs need to be checked (*id1* vs *id2*).

Final table will look like this:

```
id1 id2  var1 var2
12a 16e  66   1.0
13b 17f  9    2.0
14c 18g  48   NaN
15d 19h  13   3.0
```

All "speedy" solutions are highly appriciated.

Comment: I don't get it. Where do the values for `var1` in the result come from? Why did the `var2` column disappear? Does it matter which one of the two matching rows is removed?

Comment: The code was edited, with the addition of the executed DF output, and given the execution and the np.random.randit function the numbers changed. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe is possible sort columns per rows and filter only first rows by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and inverting mask by `~`:

```
np.random.seed(2018)

df = pd.DataFrame({'id1' : ['12a', '13b', '14c', '15d', '16e', '18g', '17f', '19h']
                     ,'id2' : ['16e', '17f', '18g', '19h','12a', '14c','13b', '15d']
                     ,'var1' : [i for i in range(8)]
                     ,'var2' : list(np.random.randint(100, size = 8))
                     ,'var3' : [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 34]
})

df = df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['id1', 'id2']], 1)).duplicated()]
print (df)
   id1  id2  var1  var2  var3
0  12a  16e     0    62   1.0
1  13b  17f     1    59   2.0
2  14c  18g     2    58   NaN
3  15d  19h     3    72   3.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['id1', 'id2']], 1)))
     0    1
0  12a  16e
1  13b  17f
2  14c  18g
3  15d  19h
4  12a  16e
5  14c  18g
6  13b  17f
7  15d  19h

print (~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['id1', 'id2']], 1)).duplicated())
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Yeah, that one blew it out of the water! Thanks for your input, easy and smart to sort axis = 1 and boolean following that, didnt think of it that way.